# How to access Git --mirror of rep

Tags: git, github

If we backup the git repos with the following commands

```
git clone --mirror gitolite@git:projectname.git
```

how can I access the project.. if I go into projectname it looks like a server repo NOT one that I can for seeing my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--mirror` implies `--bare`. You can still look at files using `git` tools (`log`, `show`, `cat-file`, `ls-tree`, etc. or `gitk` for a visual tool). If you want to look around with non-`git` tools, though, you might `git clone /path/to/my/local/copy/of/projectname.git /some/new/path`. You can always delete that second clone when you are done looking around; or keep it if you need to reference it for whatever reason...